# Output the contents of a folder to a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I am relatively new and inexperienced in the world of C#. Therefore, this question probably warrants a simlpe answer! However, I am attempting to develop a basic windows forms application which loops through a folder on a server and returns its results in a textbox. The problem that I have is that I have managed to output to the text box although System.String[] is repeated as opposed to the contents of the folder! Any help would be greatly appreciated;

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string[] StagedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\"+textBox1.Text+@"\\d$\\EDU");

     foreach (string file in StagedFiles)
     {
          textBox2.Text += StagedFiles + Environment.NewLine;
     }    
 }
```

Comment: I've removed a lot of the code that had nothing to do with your question, you should try to only include relevant code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreach needs to show the `file`, but you are showing the array

```
string[] StagedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\"+textBox1.Text+@"\\d$\\EDU");

        foreach (string file in StagedFiles)
        {

            textBox2.Text += file + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```